# Python - strings in list to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension, numpy-ndarray

I have the following list 'list1' of strings:

```
list1= ['mz', '-3956901.50', '-1310316.62', '-505251.812', '-6262072.50', '-0.781772032E+10-0.113921731E+11']
```

I want to convert columns 2 to the last column to a numpy array:

```
np.asarray(list[1:],dtype='float')
```

The problem is that I get a ValueError due to the last item in the list.
How do I split the last item first into two strings (due to the space which is missing in the delimiter)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. Split the last value in the list by split with delimiter '-'
2. Add the delimiter in case of a not empty string (split will also return empty strings)
3. Remove the last value in the list and add the split string

```
list1= ['mz', '-3956901.50', '-1310316.62', '-505251.812', '-6262072.50', '-0.781772032E+10-0.113921731E+11']

delimeter = "-"
splited_string_with_delemeter =  [delimeter+splited_string for splited_string in list1[-1].split(delimeter) if splited_string]

list2 = list1[:-1] + splited_string_with_delemeter
```

Then you'll be able to create the NumPy array:

```
np.asarray(list2[1:],dtype='float')
```

The result is:

```
array([-3.95690150e+06, -1.31031662e+06, -5.05251812e+05, -6.26207250e+06,
       -7.81772032e+09, -1.13921731e+10])
```

Answer (score 0):

For the list1's last item, you can use `eval()` function to convert it to number, then your code will work:

```
list2 = np.asarray([eval(x) for x in list1[1:]],dtype='float')
```

the result is:

```
array([-3.95690150e+06, -1.31031662e+06, -5.05251812e+05, -6.26207250e+06,
       -1.92098934e+10])
```